# Add Android Fragment to InfoWindow Contents

Tags: android, infowindow, android-maps-v2

I'm writing an Android application that targets 4.0 and up and I'm using Google Maps v2. I'd like to set the contents of an `InfoWindow` with a `Fragment`. Does anyone know if it's possible?

My class implements `InfoWindowAdapter` and here's the relevant code:

```
//
// InfoWindowAdapter interface
//

@Override
public View getInfoContents (Marker marker) {
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this.getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_details, layout);

    MapDetailsFragment frag = new MapDetailsFragment();
    // TODO: How to add this fragment to v???

    return v;
}

@Override
public View getInfoWindow (Marker marker) {
    return null;
}
```

I've tried the following code after instantiating `frag`:

```
this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_map_details, frag).commit();
```

But `R.id.fragment_map_details` is from the `R.layout.map_details` and thus the `FragmentManager` doesn't know anything about it yet.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The view returned from adapter is not a live view, but is transformed into a bitmap, so no code associated with this view (like button clicks) will ever execute.

The same case would be for fragments, so you may stop trying that and instead create a layout that binds together map_details and fragment layout. A use of include in xml will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen anyone achieve it and I don't think it is possible as it's a simple view that is created for you, meaning a lot happens behind your back.

Comment: I think you're right. I've had at it for a few days now without any luck. Fortunately I was able to make most of the methods in that fragment static, so I was able to inflate the view and set all of the fields using the static methods. Not ideal, but not duplicating code either.

Answer (score 0):

Three suggestions:

1. The transaction and the commit is asynchronous. You could try calling http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions(). However, I got exceptions at one point when I tried to use that. But you might have more luck with it.
2. Otherwise, you could try adding the fragment as regular subview to your container by replacing `R.id.fragment_map_details` with the view returned from `frag.getView()`. That's just a wild guess, however. Maybe you're not supposed to make use of that return value in that way. (I've gotten a bit cautious when it comes to Android's API...)
3. From https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows (under "Custom info windows"):

> To update the info window later (for example, after an image has loaded), call showInfoWindow().

So, if you can find a way to get notified when the fragment transaction is complete then you could call that method to update the info window.