# Google Maps Android API - Custom InfoWindow with Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, infowindow, layout-inflater

### **EDIT:**  The gist of this question is: How do I inflate a Fragment in a Google Maps InfoWindow in Android.  See below for my attempt.  Thanks!

---

I have a Google Map on a Fragment in my app and I was able to get a sub-Fragment to inflate where I tap on the screen, but I need the sub-Fragment to remain on the original touch location, so I decided to try to use an InfoWindow by creating a marker at the touch point and automatically opening an InfoWindow.

However, I am having issues with attaching the Fragment to the InfoWindow.  Here is what I have so far:

```
    private View fragmentLayout;
    private RelativeLayout fragmentMapLayout;
    private MapView mv;
    private GoogleMap gm;
    private RelativeLayout fragmentContainer;
    private FrameLayout fragmentContainerLayout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        fragmentLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        fragmentMapLayout = (RelativeLayout) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.map_fragment_layout);

        mv = (MapView) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mv.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mv.getMapAsync(this);

        return fragmentLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        gm = map;
        gm.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        gm.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
                float pX = (float) point.latitude;
                float pY = (float) point.longitude;

                gm.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(pX, pY))
                    .alpha(0.0f)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.t_box01))
                    .title("title")).showInfoWindow();

            }
        });
        gm.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                infoWindowLayout = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_container, null);
                fragmentContainerLayout = (FrameLayout) infoWindowLayout.findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);

                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    transaction.add(fragmentContainerLayout.getId(), new FragmentTwo(), "fragment_id");
                    transaction.commit();

                return fragmentContainerLayout;
            }
        });
    }
```

XML fragment_container.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

</FrameLayout>
```

Obviously, some extraneous code is also missing, but this is the code that concerns this issue.  I am getting this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.example.exampleapp, PID: 18936
                                                                   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0f00d1 (com.example.exampleapp:id/fragment_container) for fragment FragmentTwo{2ad9a637 #5 id=0x7f0f00d1 fragment_id}
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

This same method of inflating FragmentTwo worked when trying to insert it directly into the main Fragment, but something is different when trying to insert it into the InfoWindow.

I'm not sure why it can't find the ID of a view that is already in xml.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have specified the correct layout in `setContentView()`. The ID passed into `FragmentTransaction.add()` in your case `R.id.fragment_container` must be a child of the layout specified in `setContentView()`.

One possible issue is using the `getFragmentManager()`, try to use `getChildFragmentManager` when calling a fragment.

Here's a useful link for Fragment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: I think I'm understanding the problem now, thanks to your answer.  Basically, I need the added view to be a child of the view inflated for my parent Activity (Fragment in this case), but the issue here is that since I am trying to add this Sub-Fragment to an InfoWindow, I need the view to be added dynamically to the InfoWindow, and not to the Parent View that holds the actual map.  Does that make sense?  How do I add the new view to the parent view holding the map, but not have it locked into the parent?  I need it to be independent and returned by the getInfoContents() method...

Answer (score 0):

See [Add Android Fragment to InfoWindow Contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015646/add-android-fragment-to-infowindow-contents/21119194)

> The view returned from adapter is not a live view, but is transformed
>   into a bitmap, so no code associated with this view (like button
>   clicks) will ever execute.
>
> The same case would be for fragments, so you may stop trying that and
>   instead create a layout that binds together map_details and fragment
>   layout. A use of include in xml will probably work.